# How to save an SQL query result in C/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I am new too programming. 
How can i save the result of the query "SELECT Gewenstetempratuur FROM SensorValue" as an int variable so i can use it later.
I am using a mysql database.

```
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <mysql.h> 
#include <my_global.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
//the for loop is so ite gets updated frequently 
for(;;){
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

        //Conection Values
        char *server = "server";
        char *user = "user";
        char *password = "pass";
        char *database = "database";

        //Making the connection to the database
        conn = mysql_init(NULL);
        if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
        user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        }
        //The query i want to save the result from
        //"SELECT Gewenstetempratuur FROM SensorValue"

    usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _save_? As textfile report, or into another data base table?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably meant is how do I generate a sql query in a variable and use it later.

In C, you can use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) function and generate a buffer:

```
char buf[1204];
char *value = "Gewenstetempratuur";
char *table = "SensorValue";

snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "SELECT %s from %s", value, table);

mysql_real_query(conn, buf, strlen(buf));
```

and so on.

Comment: Sorry i know i am vague but what i am trying to is getting information from my database and save that information as an variable. For example if the int value 20 is saved in my database under Gewenstetemperatuur i want to save that 20 as an variable.

Comment: You can use mysql_store_result() and mysql_field_count() to get the rows and read them each. See the [manua](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-field-count.html)l for an example.